# Disable automatic LaTeX symbol replacement in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When editing RMarkdown files in Visual Studio Code, the editor automatically replaces many LaTeX-style sequences with their unicode 'equivalents'. E.g., when I type `\sum` followed by a space, it is converted to `∑`. While this is convenient in some cases, it is catastrophic when trying to embed LaTeX source into my file for rendering later on. Typing something like `$\sum \sqrt {x_i}$` is converted to `$∑ √ {x_i}$`, which renders quite differently. Even pressing "escape" when the suggested replacements show up does not prevent the substitution.

Is there a way to turn this off? I've looked through the settings quite thoroughly and cannot find a way to do so. Any help would be appreciated!

(The workaround I've come up with is to copy a single space character and paste it after my symbol instead of pressing the space key on the keyboard.)

Visual Studio Code Version: 1.63.2
Mac OS 10.14.6

Comment: Could be an extension that is doing that.  Maybe one added those as snippets?  You might be able to delete them from the Command Palette/InsertSnippet.

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea. There are about 13 snippets available, but none of them are related to special symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had an extension installed called ["Fast Unicode Math Characters"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GuidoTapia2.unicode-math-vscode) which, true to it's name, was inserting unicode math characters

Disabling this fixed the issue.

(I decided to answer my own question rather than deleting the question in case someone else has a similar issue)